# Can someone please help me determine whether this matrix is positive semi-definite?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-calculus, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I want to demonstrate the convexity of my problem by proving that the matrix $\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{a}(\theta) \boldsymbol{a}^H(\theta)$, where
$$
\boldsymbol{a}(\theta) = \left[1 \quad e^{j\pi\sin(\theta)} \quad e^{j\pi2\sin(\theta)} \quad \cdots e^{j\pi(M-1)\sin(\theta)}\right]^T, \quad \theta\in\mathbb{R}
$$
It is positive semi-definite (PSD). However, I am having difficulty proving this and would appreciate any help demonstrating that $\boldsymbol{A}$ is indeed a PSD matrix.

Comment: Every matrix of the form $XX^H$ (where $X$ denotes a possibly non-square matrix) is positive semidefinite, because $y^HXX^Hy=\|X^Hy\|^2\ge0$ for every vector $y$.